# Java netty AbstractChannelHandlerContext invokeExceptionCaught

Tags: java, netty, ioexception

I recently discovered an issue after updating my netty lib to Netty 4.
I am running a game server, and every time a player "logs out" in a non-proper way (ie. clicking the X button on the client, or simply losing connection to the server) the server prompts this error message in the CMD:

```
aug 29, 2015 8:38:01 PM io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext invokeExceptionCaught
WARNING: An exception was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
java.io.IOException: De externe host heeft een verbinding verbroken
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the code used to start the networking of the server:

```
address = new InetSocketAddress(43594);
bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
bootstrap.childHandler(new NettyChannelInitializer());
bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
bootstrap.group(new NioEventLoopGroup());
bootstrap.bind(address);
```

If anyone could tell me how I could atleast remove the exception message, I would be glad :D. It doesn't give any further issues to the server nor client, but it only prompts out this warning every time it happens

Kind regards, Alex

EDIT: My NettyChannelInitializer class:

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;

public final class NettyChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

        ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new RS2Encoder()).addLast("decoder", new RS2LoginProtocol()).addLast("handler", new NettyChannelHandler());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to trap this exception in your handler (created in your NettyChannelInitializer()) by overriding the following method:

```
void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception;
```

Comment: Could you maybe tell me a bit more about "overriding the method", I am not yet familiar with it.

Comment: Simply, in your handler, instead of having the default implementation (which simply forward the exception until it is caught by ChannelHandlerContext), you add (override) the same method but inside catch this exception (without forwarding it).

Comment: Thank you! After some trial and error I finally managed to figure it out.